# Horizontal scroll on center div

Tags: html, css, scrollbars

I have a question regarding simple HTML and CSS.
First, look at this illustration:

[image]

I am making a page with multiple background images, each having the width: 1600px (blue, pink and green on the picture).

The main area of the page (yellow) is centered (margin: 0 auto;) and have the width: 800px.

I want it to be so, that the browser-horizontal-scrollbar only appear, if the browser window is smaller than the center area (800px).

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks for any help and sorry about the awfull layout and colors ;)

Edit:

What i did so far:

i have tried to make the tyupical center div in wrapper:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="child">
```

---

```
#wrap{ width:1600px; }
#child{ width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

However, naturally the scrolls appear as for the entire wrape div, i have no idea what to do from here?

Comment: Explain what you did and where you got stuck right now? Post your efforts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think is** **possible** **throw** `position`

**As like this**

**HTML**

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one2"></div>
<div class="one3"></div>

<div class="parent">
Hello i m cente div <br>
Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>Hello i m cente div <br>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.one, .one2, .one3{
    height:200px;
}
.one{
    background:red;
}
.one2{
    background:green;
}
.one3{
    background:yellow;
}
.parent{
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px; // width according to your design
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; // according to your width / 2 and define -margin
    top:0;

}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xnJ4m/)**

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
if ( $(window).width > 800 ){
    $("#thediv").css("overflow-x","hidden");
}
else{
    $("#thediv").css("overflow-x","scroll");
}
```

Comment: @BeerFunding i actually changed it a bit. i was mixing jquery with javascript. i think this should work. you can do it with `@media screen and` as well

Comment: @he has got a much simpler solution. but if you want to actually show a scrollbar that is inside the center div i think you might need to do the method i posted

Comment: i just tried your solution as well, it works as well. The css however, got better in with the rest of the code that i allready did.